# Change fa2latex label command

Tags: latex, knitr, psych

I am using knitr and rstudio to write a report. I am attempting to print the results to a factor analysis using the `fa2latex()` function in the `psych` package. I am wanting to reference the resulting table in the text of my report. The `fa2latex` function prints a latex label command, however I have not seen a way to edit the latex command. 
I know I could edit the label after the tex file has been created, but I would like to do it in my rnw file. Does anyone know how to change the default label command in the latex output that results from the `fa2latex` function in the `psych` package.

Here is some code to use as an example.

```
library(psych)
data(Thurstone)
fa.Thurstone<-fa(Thurstone)
fa2latex(fa.Thurstone)
```

The results are this:

```
% fa2latex % fa.Thurstone 
\begin{tiny} \begin{table}[htdp]\caption{fa2latex}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular} {l r r r }
 \multicolumn{ 3 }{l}{ A factor analysis table from R } \cr 
 \hline Variable  &   MR1  &  MR1.1  &  MR1.2 \cr 
  \hline 
Sentences   &  0.87  &  0.75  &  0.25 \cr 
 Vocabulary   &  0.88  &  0.77  &  0.23 \cr 
 Sent.Completion   &  0.83  &  0.70  &  0.30 \cr 
 First.Letters   &  0.62  &  0.39  &  0.61 \cr 
 4.Letter.Words   &  0.61  &  0.37  &  0.63 \cr 
 Suffixes   &  0.59  &  0.34  &  0.66 \cr 
 Letter.Series   &  0.57  &  0.32  &  0.68 \cr 
 Pedigrees   &  0.64  &  0.41  &  0.59 \cr 
 Letter.Group   &  0.52  &  0.27  &  0.73 \cr 
\hline \cr SS loadings & 4.32 &  \cr \hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\label{default}
\end{table} 
\end{tiny}
```

What I am wondering is if there is a way to change the default in the `\label{default}` command.

I have tried

```
fa2latex(fa.Thurstone, label="newlabel")
```

but this tells me

```
    Error in fa2latex(fa.Thurstone, label = "newlabel") : 
  unused argument (label = "newlabel")
```

Does anyone know a way to change this?

Comment: You can always try using `xtable` on the output of `fa`. It will give you more flexibility for these kinds of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no, but it is an easy patch.  Change line 1 to include "label"

```
"fa2latex" <- 
function(f,digits=2,rowlabels=TRUE,apa=TRUE,short.names=FALSE,font.size ="tiny", heading="A factor analysis table from R",caption="fa2latex",label="default") {
```

and then change the lines defining footer to

```
footer <- paste(footer,"
\\end{tabular}
\\end{center}
\\label{",label,"}
\\end{table} 
\\end{",font.size,"}
",sep=""
)
```

I will include this correction in the next release.

Bill

Comment: Version 1.3.10 is now released and has that feature.